# Cannot boot on Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I'm totally new to Ubuntu and was really interested in it. I followed the tutorial on how to install it in dualboot with Windows 7 carefully, and gave it a try.

Ubuntu 14.04 is booting fine with GRUB, but after trying to boot on Windows 7, I got a BSOD. Repair tools did nothing so I searched on the internet.

I've found this thing called Boot Repair, but instead of giving more choices in GRUB (which didn't help at all), nothing changed. I got the ubuntu paste from Boot Repair here : http://paste.ubuntu.com/12279582/

If you could help, I'd be really happy ! I must miss something really stupid but as I said, it's the first time I installed Ubuntu in my life.

Note : I haven't made any restore point from my Win 7, and I can't figure out how to get this Windows Repair Kit CD (I know, I'm stupid)

Answer (score 0):

```
First boot on your Windows Vista/7/8 installation DVD.

If you have one of the many OEM computers that didn't come with a Windows installation disk, you can get the same effect with a Windows repair disk, which you can download (eg Win7-32bit, Win7 64bit) or create from another Windows Vista/7/8 computer (see this page for Win7 and Make your own Windows repairCD, and Windows 8 UEFI repair USB must be FAT32, other Win8 guide). When you get to the Regional settings, select your Location/Keyboard setting then click next. On the next page, click on "Repair your computer." On the next page, if it finds your Windows installation, make sure it is UNSELECTED before clicking next. Then click on "Command prompt". From there, type in the following 2 commands:
```

bootrec.exe /fixboot

bootrec.exe /fixmbr

```
Now close the two windows and click "Restart." Take out your Windows DVD and hopefully, you will be left with your Windows bootloader.
```

Comment: Tried what you said, 'Operation Successful' for the two commands but after rebooting still getting BSOD :/ Thanks anyways